# Check if XOR is associative

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I can thnk of only one way to tackle this problem, however, it is very tedious.
$$ a \oplus b \iff (a \land \neg b) \lor(\neg b \land a)$$
And so now I evaluate, by definition, $(a \oplus b) \oplus c$ and $a \oplus(b\oplus c)$ And then, using the associativity of OR and AND, I get the same expression for arrangements of parentheses.

However, is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: A truth table? Or showing that a string of XOR is true iff an odd number of the variables are true, no matter how you associate them.

Comment: It's surprising that you haven't been introduced to truth tables...

Comment: I am a little bit ashamed that I haven't thought of a truth table in the first place... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using a logical calculator and bitwise operations,

$$(55_H\oplus33_H)\oplus0F_H=66_H\oplus0F_H=69_H$$

$$55_H\oplus(33_H\oplus0F_H)=55_H\oplus3C_H=69_H$$

Comment: I hope you will see the rationale behing this computation.

Comment: @Arthur: of course, but I wanted the OP to guess.

Answer (score 0):

We did those kind of problems last year for an exam. The teacher asked us to solve it using your approach,  but we could also use truth tables for a lower score. It would be like this:[xor truth table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGabh.png)